# Add a column in the output file to trace the record from the original input file

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I have 3 input csv files, each one of them has the same format and the records inside each of those files are mutually exclusive.

```
input1.csv  
input2.csv
input3.csv
```

I want to merge the above files into one output file.

```
cat input1.csv input2.csv inpput3.csv > output.csv
```

Requirement - The `output.csv` file must have an additional column that will contain the filename against each line indicating the input file that contains that line.

**Example**

```
input1.csv      input2.csv      input3.csv
----------      ----------      ----------
123             abc             i              
456             def             ii
789             ghi             iii

output.csv
----------
123      input1.csv
456      input1.csv
789      input1.csv
abc      input2.csv
def      input2.csv
ghi      input2.csv
i        input3.csv
ii       input3.csv
iii      input3.csv
```

In the example my input file contains only one column. But it can have multiple columns as well. The output file is a csv file. Delimiter in all the files is TAB - `\t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something to get you started:

```
$ awk '{print $0, FILENAME}' f{1..3}
123 f1
456 f1
789 f1
abc f2
def f2
ghi f2
i f3
ii f3
iii f3
```

or if you have multiple columns

```
$ cat f1
123  000
456  111
789  222

$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++)print $i, FILENAME}' f{1..3}
123 f1
000 f1
456 f1
111 f1
789 f1
222 f1
abc f2
def f2
ghi f2
i f3
ii f3
iii f3
```

Formatting of the output is left as an exercise...

Comment: +1 `awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) printf $i FS ; print FILENAME }' f{1..3}` for formatted output

Comment: @JS웃 - that's one way but the OP didn't state how multiple columns should be presented. Might as well just use `awk '{printf $0 FS ; print FILENAME }' f{1..3}` :-)

Comment: Yes i want to retain the format of the input file in case of multiple columns. Hence, `awk '{printf $0 FS ; print FILENAME }' f{1..3}` seems to be a good option! Thanks.

Comment: Is `awk '{print $0, FILENAME}' f{1..3}` not sufficient, for multicolumn input files also?

Comment: @anishsane - you are right. At the time of writing, the OPs output requirements wasn't clear...

Comment: ^^ @FredrikPihl: Yes, understood that. I was just trying to ask, if without specifying `FS=,`, can `printf $0 FS` work?

Comment: @anishsane - depend on what you mean :-). Above the builtin variable FS (FieldSeparator) is used for adding WS befor printing the FILENAME. The CSV-files used have TAB-delimited fields so no need for specifying comma as field-separator using `FS=,` or `-F,`

Comment: @FredrikPihl:
Oh, I missed that output file part. So based on output file, it's the best guess, that the input file also has tab separated data & not comma separated.

Comment: @anishsane - As OP puts it: " Delimiter in all the files is TAB - \t." :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32431/discussion-between-anishsane-and-fredrik-pihl)

Comment: The output file that is generated should be tab delimited. However, the additional column added at the end of each line isn't tab separated. How to print a tab character between `print $0` and `FILENAME`?

Comment: @PankajParashar - just add a tab `'\t'`, try: `$ awk '{print $0"\t"FILENAME}' f{1..3}`